# Oozie : Sqoop dynamic target directory

Tags: linux, hadoop, sqoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am executing `sqoop` job from `Oozie` workflow. I am able to create target directory with static names in `sqoop` command as follows.

```
<action name="table1" cred="">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <command>job --exec EMPLOYEE --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://<host>:<port>/sqoop -- --target-dir /user/test/Employee/20150126</command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="kill" />
</action>
```

I need to create dynamic target directory with date. I tried with following, but not working.

```
<action name="table1" cred="">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <command>job --exec EMPLOYEE --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://<host>:<port>/sqoop -- --target-dir /user/test/Employee/$(date +%Y%m%d)</command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="kill" />
</action>
```

while running showing following error.

```
 3622 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.2.0
  3957 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Error parsing arguments for import:
  3957 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Unrecognized argument: +%Y%m%d)
  Intercepting System.exit(1)
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to create a job property like `${today}` then inline it in the scoop action. sqoop action command isn't a bash call so `$(date +%Y%m%d)` won't work

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the coordina time from coordinator.xml to workflow.xml. So in workflow you can have lik this

```
/user/test/Employee/${timePassedFromCoordinator}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use shell action to assign the env-var as a date by following method.

**"variable.sh"**

```
#!/bin/sh
outputDir =$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

**Workflow.xml**

```
<action name='shell1'>
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <exec>variable.sh</exec>
                      (or)
            <env-var>[outputDir=$(date +%Y%m%d)]</env-var>
        </shell>
        <ok to="table1" />
        <error to="fail" />
</action>
<action name="table1" cred="">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <command>job --exec EMPLOYEE --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://<host>:<port>/sqoop -- --target-dir /user/test/Employee/$(outputDir)</command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="kill" />
</action>
```

Comment: I tried with above code, but it is creating directory with name '$(outputDir)'

Comment: Tyr like below instead of <command>....</command> ,                                                   <arg> job </arg>
            <arg>-- exec</arg>
            <arg> EMPLOYEE </arg>
            <arg>-- meta </arg>
            <arg>- connect </arg>
            <arg>--target-dir</arg>
            <arg> jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://<host>:<port>/sqoop</arg>
            <arg>--target-dir</arg>
            <arg>”$(outputDir)”</arg>

Answer (score 0):

In coordinator you can get the date and format in required format as under

```
<action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>${WF_Maig_1}</app-path>
            <configuration>

                <property><name>currentbatchtime</name><value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(),0,'DAY'),"yyyy-MM-dd")}</value></property>
                <property><name>nextbatchtime</name><value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(),1,'DAY'),"yyyy-MM-dd")}</value></property>
            </configuration>
        </workflow>
    </action>
```

Now you can use /user/test/Employee/${currentbatchtime} in workflow.xml and in properties file too

Answer (score 0):

capture-output helped for me!.

```
<action name='custom-var'>
   <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
      ...
     <exec>set_variable.sh</exec>
     <file>set_variable.sh</file>
     <capture-output/>
   </shell>
</action>

<action name='sqoop-test'>
  <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
    ...
    <command> --target-dir /test/${wf:actionData('custom-var')['var1']}  --m 1 </command>
  </sqoop>
</action>

set_variable.sh
echo "var1=$(date +%Y/%m/%d)"
```